# How to make an app running inside a docker container available to the local network?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am given access to a docker container, I use ssh to get inside the container. `ssh user@192.168.1.76 -p 2222`

Now, I have deployed an app inside the docker container (from the container), in port 8000.

How can I access the app from my local network?

N.B: I tried `sudo ufw allow 8000`, and `hostname -a` to get the IP, but can't access the app on `IP:8000` from the local network.

Now, the container was run with `--net=host`, so all the ports of the container are mapped to the host ones. So, I had to change the host in app to `0.0.0.0` to get the app live in the local network.

Comment: check https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: The container need to specify the port mapping then you deploy the container with docker run .... -p 8000:8000

Comment: Actually, the container was run with `--net = host`, I had to change the host in app to `0.0.0.0` and now I can access it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-p 8000:8000` as an argument to `docker run`. Then you can access this port with the IP of the host machine.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/